# What does the selection of class in IB do?

Tags: xcode, class, identity

Newbie question.

I'm building a cocoa app with xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard. Suppose I want a table view with a view controller. I select File->New->New File, select Objective-C class, name it foo and specify that it is a subclass of NSViewController. xcode creates foo.h, foo.m and foo.xib for me. Then I create another new class, name it bar, specify that it is a descendent of NSTableView, and xcode creates bar.h and bar.m.

When I open foo.xib in IB, I see a blue rectangle labeled "Custom View". I select that view and then in the Identity Inspector set its class to bar, the NSTableView descendent that I just created. I would expect that the appearance of the custom view in IB would change to that of a TableView, almost as if I had dragged an NSTableView from the object library and dropped it on the custom view. But that doesn't happen. Instead the name of the custom view just changes to bar. I can't tell whether I have a Table View or not.

What is the right way to create a new table view and controller?

Comment: Drag in a table view, then change its class to bar? I don't think IB is smart enough otherwise.

Comment: Oh. Okay. Should I drop the table view on the custom view? Or should I delete the custom view first?

Comment: I'm a bit out of date on OS X view controllers, sorry. Probably safest to drop it onto the custom view.